# NoClassDefFoundError exception when loading PApplet in mozilla

Tags: java

im having hard time running my PApplet in firefox.

here is my code:

```
import processing.core.*; 
import processing.data.*; 

import saito.objloader.*; 
import processing.opengl.*; 

 import java.applet.*; 
import java.awt.Dimension; 
import java.awt.Frame; 
import java.awt.event.*; 


public class load_and_rotate_3d extends PApplet {

OBJModel model; 
float rotateX;
float rotateY;

public void setup() {  

  size(800, 600, OPENGL);  

  model = new OBJModel(this, "Human Heart.obj", "relative", POLYGON); 

  model.translateToCenter(); 
  model.scale(15);  
  noStroke();

}

 public void draw() {   

  background(255);  

  lights();  
  translate(width/2, height/2, 0);   
  rotateX(rotateY);  
  rotateY(rotateX);

  model.draw(); 

  }

  public void mouseDragged() {  

    rotateX += (mouseX - pmouseX) * 0.01f; 
    rotateY -= (mouseY - pmouseY) * 0.01f;

  }

  boolean drawLines = false;

  static public void main(String[] passedArgs) {

    String[] appletArgs = new String[] { "load_and_rotate_3d" };

       if (passedArgs != null) {

         PApplet.main(concat(appletArgs, passedArgs));

       } else {
           PApplet.main(appletArgs);
       }
     }
    }
```

here is html:

```
  <html>
   <head>
     <title>PApplet</title>
   </head>

  <body>

 <applet code="load_and_rotate_3d.java" codebase = "../source" width="800"       height="600">
 </applet>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Environment:
Windows7.

The code is written in Processing then exported to Eclipse.When i open it in mozilla or ie i get NoClassDefFoundError exception.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the code's file name?

Answer (score 0):

This type of error means that one or class/jar files failed at the runtime.

To solv this problem just check if all imported class/jar are present at the runtime